# grep on variable passed to function

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I am passing a variable to a function that has been loaded from a config file. This variable is in turn passed on to a grep. I have tried several ways to expand the search variable ($1) but none seem to work, however the file to search works fine ($2).

Can someone advise what is the correct way to present the variable to the grep function. I have tried
"$1", "${1}", $1, ${1}, "${!1}

**UPDATE** Based on answers I have updated the script.sh to refelect the actual script complexity as it still does not work.

thanks
Art

***Working code with no variable for `RouteTableId`***

```
MyVar=$(grep -m 1 "RouteTableId" $2)
```

***Not Working code with variable for `RouteTableId`***

config.file

```
myTerm="RouteTableId"
myFile="my.file"
```

script.sh

```
. config.file 
myFunction(){
    mySubFunction(){        
        myVar=$(grep -m 1 "$1" $2)
        echo $myVar
     }
    mySubFunction ${!1} ${!2} 
}
myFunction "myTerm" "myFile"
```

**UPDATE**
I have done some more tests and it turns out that when passing variables between functions, in some circumstances the numbering order changes if one of the sequence is null. for example if i call myFunction with the following, the 2nd variable being null

```
myFunction "myTerm" "blah" "myFile"
```

then myFunction will see the following

```
echo "${!1}, ${!2}, ${!3}" 
RouteTableId,,my.file
```

and then passing this to mySubFunction

```
mySubFunction ${!1} ${!3}
```

gives from within mySubFunction

```
echo "${!1}, ${!2}, ${!3}" 
RouteTableId,my.file,
```

so it seems the null is being removed in the order and the subsequent variables are being brought forward in the number order. 
If someone can validate and explain why I would appreciate it.

thx
Art

Comment: @Ed, glad I can bring something new to a distinguished career :). Yes there are several sub functions that are called on other processing options. Happy Festivus!

Comment: @artvanderlay are you sure you can use sub functions like that ?Not 100% but pretty sure you can't declare a function in a function.Even if you can though i think it would be better to declare them as separate functions and then just include the call in the other one.

Answer (score 3):

You are not passing the *values* of the variables but the variable names themselves as values.

i.e.

```
myFunction "myTerm" "myFile"
```

should be

```
myFunction "$myTerm" "$myFile"
```

Comment: yes you are correct so I updated my Q to reflect more of the complexity. thx Art

Answer (score 2):

If this isn't what you expect, you should edit your question to better define what it is you do expect:

```
$ cat my.file
foo
Here it is: RouteTableId
bar
$
$ cat config.file
myTerm="RouteTableId"
myFile="my.file"
$
$ cat script.sh
. config.file
myFunction() {
    mySubFunction() {
        myVar=$(grep -m 1 "$1" "$2")
        echo "$myVar"
    }
    mySubFunction "${!1}" "${!2}"
}
myFunction "myTerm" "myFile"
$
$ ./script.sh
Here it is: RouteTableId
```

From your recent update, I think you are confused about what `$1`, etc. means. In a shell script but outside of any function `$1` is the first arg passed to the shell script. In a function within a shell script `$1` is the first arg passed to that function, NOT the first arg passed to the shell script. So if you do:

```
func() {
   echo "$1,$2,$3"
}
func "$1" "$3"
```

then you will get the values of the first arg passed to the script (since that is also the 1st arg passed to the function), then a comma, then the 3rd arg passed to the script (since that is the 2nd arg passed to the function) and then another comma and that is all (because there is no 3rd arg passed to the function).

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: thanks for your help. Based on some thinking on your earlier posts, I started to review the actual code as it is a lot more complex. You can see my updates for my findings. For your help I have made a donation in your name to the Human fund - money for people during this festivus period.

Comment: I don't see your updates anywhere but thank you for the donation. I will, however, redirect it to making safer glue for stamps.

Comment: I see your update now. It looks like the issue is simply that you aren't quoting your variables. Naughty.... Use `"${!1}"`, not `${!1}`. Also, when you invoke `func "$1" "$3"` then inside `func` the 2nd arg (i.e. `$2`) IS the value you extracted from `$3` in the calling code so if that's not what you want then just don't do that!

Comment: I see, so a Null value is not passed as value=null, rather value ceases to exist. thx Art

Comment: No, there is no null value. You're passing 2 args to the function so inside the function $1 and $2 are populated, that's all. The fact that you are calling the function with args populated from the values of $1 and $3 as they exist in the callers context is completely irrelevant.